# Stream Builder not responding correctly with ListView.builder

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My stream builder is not rebuilding the widgets correctly when new data is deleted or added into firestore , when I add new items to the firestore it gets its name and price wrong and when i delete any item it removes the correct item on firestore but not on the front end . When i pop and push the page again from the navigator then it shows the correct list of items.

**Here is my streamBuilder code:**

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: currentStream,
                builder: (context, snap) {
                  if (snap.hasError) {
                    print(snap.error);
                  }

                  List loadedDocs = [];

                  var loadedData = snap.data;
                  if (loadedData != null) {
                    loadedDocs = loadedData.docs.reversed.toList();

                    if (loadedDocs != null) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: snap.data!.docs.length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            var item = loadedDocs.toList()[index].data()
                                as Map<String, dynamic>;

                            return ChangeNotifierProvider(
                              create: (_) => ProductItem(
                                productId: item["id"].toString(),
                                itemName: item["name"].toString(),
                                itemPrice: double.parse(
                                  item["price"].toString(),
                                ),
                                itemTask: "Wash Only",
                                itemImageUrl:
                                    item["itemImageUrl"].toString(),
                              ),
                              child: itemListItem(this.updatePage),
                            );
                          });
                    }
                  }

                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }),
```

**List Item Code**

```
 class itemListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  Function updateState;
  itemListItem(this.updateState);
  String itemName = "";
  double itemPrice = 0;
  String itemImageUrl = "";
  var itemCount = 0;
  String itemTask = list[0];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProductItem currentItem = Provider.of<ProductItem>(context);

    var locale = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    return Container(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 12),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                FadedScaleAnimation(
                  Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 80, maxWidth: 100),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          currentItem.itemImageUrl.toString(),
                          scale: 2.5,
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  durationInMilliseconds: 400,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                          Text(currentItem.itemName.toString(),
                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .headline2!
                                  .copyWith(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                          Text(' \$ ' + currentItem.itemPrice.toString(),
                              style:
                                  Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                      )),
                          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  var val = "";

                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text("Confirm Delete"),
                                    content: Text(
                                        "Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Item"),
                                    actions: [
                                      TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () async {
                                            var id = "";
                                            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                .collection("itemProduct")
                                                .get()
                                                .then((value) async {
                                              var selectedDoc = value.docs
                                                  .firstWhere((element) =>
                                                      element.data()["id"] ==
                                                      currentItem.productId
                                                          .toString());
                                              id = selectedDoc.id;
                                              await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                  .collection("itemProduct")
                                                  .doc(id)
                                                  .delete();
                                              Navigator.pop(context);
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Text("YES")),
                                      TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(context, "n");
                                          },
                                          child: Text("NO"))
                                    ],
                                  );
                                }).then((value) async {});
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I probably am doing something wrong with the changeNotifierProvider because when i pass the data like the id , name etc of the item to the widget directly without using provider it works

Comment: After reading your question, I assume you are not having any issue with Firestore but the issue is data getting incorrectly displayed on Flutter UI Stream Builder and List View Builder right?

Comment: Yep the issue the issue is related to flutter and stream builder im implementing something wrong and something i cant understand